# Status access overflow while accessing array of chars

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
FILE *input;
FILE *output;
input=fopen("in.txt", "r");
output=fopen("out.txt", "w");  
char buffer[1000];
char bytebuffer=0;
char tempchr=0;
char huffmancode[100]={0};
int bufferindex=7;

fgets(&buffer[0],255,input);

int length=0;
while (buffer[length]!=0) length++;
fputc(length,output);       
int j;
int k;
for (j=0;j<length;j++){
    tempchr=buffer[j];
    strcpy(&huffmancode[0],code[tempchr-97]);
    k=0;
    while(huffmancode[k]!=0){
        if (huffmancode[k]!='0'){
            setBit(&bytebuffer,bufferindex);
        }
        bufferindex-=1;
        if (bufferindex==-1){
            fputc(bytebuffer,output);
            bytebuffer=0;
            bufferindex=7;
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

This code is not running properly, due to this line:

```
tempchr=buffer[j];
```

This line works perfectly fine for `j < 10` but for `j >= 10` the program throws a status access overflow exception. The buffer variable is allocated for 1000 bytes, so it isn't clear why the program is failing to access an index in bounds. Why is this failing?

There are some array definitions which I didn't include. I don't think they are the problem but here they are anyways:

The `agac` array:

```
    int agac[1000]={21,12,9,7,5,
                   5,4,0,0,0,
                   0,3,2,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0
    };
```

The `sembol` array:

```
    char sembol[1000]={0,0,0,'a','b',
                      0,'f',0,0,0,
                      0,'u','k',0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0
    };
```

The array of Huffman codes:

```
    char *code[27]={ "00","01",0,0,0,
                     "11",0,0,0,0,    
                     "101",0,0,0,0,    
                     0,0,0,0,"100",            
                     0,0,0,0,0,            
                     0,0
    };
```

Comment: Why the manual counting of the length? `fgets` properly terminates the read string so you can use `strlen`.

Comment: I just bashed the first idea to keyboard. Fighting with deadlines, you know.

Comment: Are you compiling with all optimisations disabled?  Optimisations have a tendency to confuse the debugger when it tries to match machine-code instructions to source-code lines.

Comment: You don't show the declaration of `code`, could you do that as well? Also, are you certain that the input file only contain small letters? If it don't, `tempchr-97` might be less than zero.

Comment: @charlesworth, no optimisations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, you can find the declarations below. I modify the in file by hand so they are all small ascii letters.

Comment: no spaces, no newlines, nothing. just small letters.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have commented that all characters in your file are just small letters so their code is >= 97. But it is possible that there is a new line at the end of the file (some editors will put it even if you didn't had a new line), which is causing the bug.

Note that unlike gets, fgets include the newline character in the buffer (see [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code then run it:

```
tempchr=buffer[j];
if(tmpchr < 97 || (tmpchr-97 > 26))
{
  printf("bug found");
}
strcpy(&huffmancode[0],code[tempchr-97]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one problem:

```
fputc(length,output);
```

This will only write the lowest (least-significant) byte of `length` (which is an `int`) to the output file. It will write it in binary form, which seems very odd for a file opened with a `.txt` extension.

You probably want:

```
fprintf(output, "%d\n", length);
```